# Why am I getting this HTTP load failed when trying to sign up to Firebase through my app?

Tags: ios, http, firebase, swift3

I don't understand why this isn't working. Here is my log from the console:

```
2017-06-03 18:14:07.012 Study M8[84528:3251785] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 10
2017-06-03 18:14:07.068 Study M8[84528] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport
2017-06-03 18:14:07.217 Study M8[84528] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4000000 started
2017-06-03 18:14:07.218 Study M8[84528] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2017-06-03 18:14:07.218 Study M8[84528] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-06-03 18:14:07.327 Study M8[84528] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-06-03 18:14:07.331 Study M8[84528] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-06-03 18:14:07.958 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:08.213 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:08.351 Study M8[84528:3251785] <Firebase/Network/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000051850 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:08.355 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000056c80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:08.358 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-NET901017] <Firebase/Network/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000051850 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:08.359 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000051850 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}, with Status Code: 0
2017-06-03 18:14:08.876 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:08.880 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000004d440 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:12.881266+1000 Study M8[84528:3251785] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/jack.staples/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A86AAB47-B72B-41D0-9FE3-6BAA9F7097ED/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-06-03 18:14:12.884974+1000 Study M8[84528:3251785] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-06-03 18:14:25.386 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:25.391 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x6080002459d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:25.632 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:32.943 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:32.947 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000257100 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:14:51.945 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:14:51.949 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000248a30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:15:35.581 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:15:35.584 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000247770 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:16:31.985 Study M8[84528:3252150] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-03 18:16:31.989 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800005c140 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-03 18:16:31.990 Study M8[84528] <Error> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003007] Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

Comment: have you added NSAppTransportSecurity key to your plist?

Comment: Yes the NSExceptionDomain is in the NSAppTransportSecurity key.

Comment: check your url once, Is http is there in your url? your url must start from http://

Comment: @JitendraModi Is this in the exception?

Comment: This URL is part of a connection to firebase.

Comment: yeah got it man. I am wrong here

Comment: [This search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=HTTP+load+failed+kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL+9806) let me to an exact duplicate, first result, error -9806.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Ok can do. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @halfer Also neither of those solutions in that duplicate you found, worked.

Comment: I don't think you can have tried long enough inside of ten minutes! `:=)` Nevertheless, you are now further along - edit your question to show what things you have tried from the other question, and show how the results are different. What errors do you get now? etc.

Comment: (It's worth noting that answers are best considered good jumping off points rather than pieces of code that can be typed in verbatim to produce a fully tested solution. Experiment and keep searching).

Comment: That's the problem I don't know how they're different I have been trying to do this for the last three days. When I get the error I am hitting my sign up button to create a user in my firebase authentication database. This is all I know.

Comment: Check your logs again, and see if the output is different there. I can't see what you have tried until your question has been updated (and I don't develop for iOS anyway, just giving some hints that come to mind).

Comment: It would probably be helpful in the question to say "I have seen potential duplicate [link] and I tried possible solutions X and Y. However I think my case is different because I observe A and B". If you are posting an updated log based on new work, what was it that you tried? Put that in the question too. Currently the new question is still a "search and debug this for me please", and there is no code provided.